# python kubernetes client: How to update crd subresource status

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm trying to update the subresource "status" of a crd resource with the python kubernetes client. The customresourceapi does not seem to provide functionality for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CustomObjectsApi` to update the status using `patch` method.

**Code:**

```py
from kubernetes import client


api = client.CustomObjectsApi()
api.patch_namespaced_custom_object_status(
    name='sample-cron-tab',
    group='stable.example.com',
    version='v1',
    namespace='default',
    plural='crontabs',
    body={'status': {'replicas': 2}}
)
```

Above code will work if you are using custom resources that are namespace scoped.

If you are using cluster scope, try below code

```
api.patch_cluster_custom_object_status(
    name='sample-cron-tab',
    group='stable.example.com',
    version='v1',
    plural='crontabs',
    body={'status': {'replicas': 2}}
)
```

Comment: This eventually worked! Thanks! However, I had to provide the full body (first retrieved with list_namespaced_custom_object and then manually extended by the status property) and not only some dictionary item.